# Key for the letter “p” not working everywhere, Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

Suddenly the key "p" stoPPed working at certain Places. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 - Gnome 3.18. I found that someone had the same issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231307/key-for-the-letter-o-stopped-working-works-only-with-shift-Linux), but there is no solution Posted.

- "p" works in Activities Overview of Gnome
- "p" works in tty (ctrl +alt+ f1)
- xev doesn't register "p" correctly
- xmod shows the mappings correctly
- "p" does not work in new X-server
- "shift + p" works

Comment: Look for a grab on the key `p`. Follow the steps in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/manipulating-x-key-and-pointer-grabs-on-the-command-line/62254#62254

Comment: I tried `sleep 1; xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo` followed by Pressing "p". The log at  `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` showed no new information. Looks like xdotool does not detect p

Comment: Note that you need to press *and hold* `p` (it must be held down at the time `xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo` runs).

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I also tried `sleep 1; xdotool type p ; echo` and outPut is blank. if I try `sleep 1; xdotool type a ; echo` , the ouPut is `a`. It robably means xdotool is not detecting "p" key

Comment: So I disabled all the gnome-extensions and rebooted. the "p" key started working again. I am not sure which gnome-extension is causing the issue but at least I know the cause

Answer (score 1):

So I disabled all the gnome-extensions and rebooted. the "p" key started working again. I am not sure which gnome-extension is causing the issue but at least I know the cause

Comment: I had a similar problem with "Ctrl-Space" not working in Emacs, and it turned out it was `ibus` which captured that particular key. No idea what would capture "p", though.

Comment: The shellshape gnome extension has this p key problem

Comment: https://github.com/timbertson/shellshape/issues/172 . Wasted 2 hours see why this is haPPening .

Comment: @KnutOvesen thats it..