# bash does not know the letter 'p'

Tags: bash, bashrc, profile

My `bash` does not know the letter `p`. `zsh` does though.

When I type a `p` in bash, it simply ignores it, and even pasting in text that contains a `p` will result in no `p` in the pasted text. 
This behavior is the same across terminals (I tried, `urxvt`, `st` and `tty`)

I tried commenting out everything in my `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`, the problem still persists. Using root though, everything is fine. My `/root/.profile`, `/root/.bash_profile` and `/root/.bashrc` are symlinked to the files in my home directory. So the problem can't originate there, but it's got to be something that is different for root and my user.

I use a custom keyboard layout, but when I switch to standard US keyboard layout, the problem still persists as well.

Just to rule [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326431/key-for-the-letter-p-not-working-everywhere-ubuntu-linux) out as well: I do not use gnome.

Where else can I look?

Comment: Is there any `.inputrc` in effect?

Comment: ha, yes, that's it! I had this left in there: 
`# fix not working delete-key, see https://git.suckless.org/st/file/FAQ.html
# line 51
# printf '\033[?1h\033=' >/dev/tty` I'm using urxvt again anyways, so it doesn't matter

Comment: That was easier than I thought :) If you make your comment an answer, I can accept it

Comment: Been there, done that :)

Comment: @maddingl could you copy that content into the answer.  This would be a very good one for future readers!  I understand this was something you might have done yourself but it's good for people to understand cause -> effect.

Comment: That `printf` command doesn't belong in `~/.inputrc` which doesn't understand commands such as that. It should go in `~/.bashrc` or similar shell startup file.

Comment: Symlinking root's shell startup files elsewhere is a security issue.

Comment: Protip: *Any time* Bash's input system is "broken" and Zsh's isn't, it's probably a GNU Readline problem (as in this case). Zsh has its own input system (ZLE) that has nothing to do with Readline.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Don't suggest new users to perform major edit on other people answers. You should instead have suggested the OP to write their own answer.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: That's not what was suggested. I'd probably word it a bit differently, "into an answer" - but English is my second language, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Adding a new answer would be totally inappropriate, the information added is **NOT** a new answer but a clarification of the existing one.  To quote the help center on this:  [When should I edit posts? ... <snip> ... To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).  Adding new answers saying "thank you this was the problem ... because" is actively discouraged on stack exchange.  Such posts are frequently flagged and deleted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Besides the files you mentioned, there could be `.inputrc` in effect that changes the interpretation of the `p` key.

**Edit:** maddingl (the OP) confirms:

> That's it. I had left the following in there:
>
> ```
> # fix not working delete-key in st, see https://git.suckless.org/st/file/FAQ.html
> # line 51
> printf '\033[?1h\033=' >/dev/tty
> ```
>
> That line does fix the `delete`-key in `st`, but it also causes the described problem. I went back to `urxvt` anyways, so for me it does not matter. If the reader is using `st` and wants both working `p` and `delete`, see the [above mentioned link](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/FAQ.html) for more info.

Comment: @maddingl I don't think your edit was warrented. First of all: don't write edits using first-person. Edits should fix errors or add *small* amounts of information. IMHO instead of editing this answer you could have added your own answer instead.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: Let's not treat new users with conflicting demands. maddingl was asked to do it this [this commend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523494/bash-does-not-know-the-letter-p#comment967951_523494) on the question above.

Comment: I think the comment was suggesting that @maddlingl write his own answer, but it was written unclearly.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's what I meant. If a user edits someone else's answer/question they should do so in an "integrated manner", not like "Hey, different user here. This is what I did ...". At that point they should simply write their own answer and add a reference to the other answer.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta please don't encourage people to write new posts inappropriately.  Answers are for *new answers* not further clarification of existing answers.